# Replace http header in QNetworkReply

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I need to replace or add http header in QNetworkReply, but methods "setHeader()" and "setRawHeader()" are protected. Can I do this without creating derived class?

Comment: I believe you need to create a derived class. You could make those methods public. Don't know why they are protected.

Comment: Or, subclass QNetworkAccessManager, and create a "proxy" QNetworkReply into createRequest. There *should* be an implementation available somewhere in the qt-examples repository.

Answer (score 0):

**This is ill advised. Just a try.**

See the method const method `rawHeaderList()` at QT [github](https://github.com/qtproject/qt/blob/v4.8.6/src/network/access/qnetworkreply.cpp#L545.) repo. It is const reference to the real header object. We can use `const_cast` and add then add the header. Look into `setRawHeader`  [protected method](https://github.com/qtproject/qt/blob/v4.8.6/src/network/access/qnetworkreply.cpp#L781) to see how header is added which you can add to your code.